# including installed libraries in cmakelists

Tags: c, cmake, clion, lcm-data-marshalling

I don't always program in C, but when I do it's typically for microcontrollers, so please bear with me on this one.

I'm trying to run a simple test of a C program before I try and compile it in Matlab for a Simulink block. I'm using Clion as my IDE. If I compile on the command line with `gcc -o listener exlcm_example_t.o listener.o 'pkg-config lcm --libs'` my program compiles fine. Now, if I try to compile in my IDE I get that the system can't find the symbol for x86 etc.

I've found some similar solutions for people including other libraries, but they don't seem to work in my case. In particular, I'm trying to include the Lightweight Communications and Marshaling system [LCM](https://github.com/lcm-proj/lcm) in order to do some interprocess communication.

I've tried a couple solutions from here on SE, and they generally follow what is outlined [here](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake:How_To_Find_Libraries). In the IDEs editor, if I do `#include <lcm/lcm.h>`, I can do `Go To -> Declaration` and it will take me to the h files, so it's finding it somehow, just not where I need it.

From what I've read, if make doesn't have a module for the library, I'll need to use my own *.cmake file. I happen to have found one [here](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/director/tree/master/cmake/modules). My directory looks like this:

MyProject:
- cmake
-- modules
--- *.cmake
- cmakelists.txt
- main.cpp

The help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Self resolved by structuring my directory as above in the original post with FindLCM.cmake, and using this cmakelists.txt file:

```
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)
    project(lcm_mp)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
    set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
    add_executable(lcm_mp ${SOURCE_FILES})
    set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/modules/")
    find_package(LCM REQUIRED lcm)
    include_directories(${LCM_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    set(LIBS ${LIBS} ${LCM_LIBRARIES})
    target_link_libraries(lcm_mp ${LIBS})
```

Any comments on improving on this file are much appreciated.